# Problem canvas position top and left jquery directly in the script

Tags: jquery, canvas

Hello I would like to position my canvas directly in the script without using css

```
var $el  = document.querySelector('.first');
const self = this;
(function() {
  var ctx, w, h, cx, cy, PI, PI_HALF, style, cos, sin, random, lineWidth, C, 
      rings, ringsLength, data;
  ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  w = 300;
  h = 300;
  cx = 79;
  cy = 79;
  rings = [];
  ringsLength = 0;
   
  PI = Math.PI;
  PI_HALF = PI / 2;
  cos = Math.cos;
  sin = Math.sin;
  random = Math.random;
 
  lineWidth = 0.1;
  C = ["#10aaac", "#10aaac", "#10aaac", "<?php echo ($params->get('colornebula')); ?>", "<?php echo ($params->get('colornebula')); ?>", "#10aaac"];
   
  data = [
    /* ring {t:total_particles, r:radius, d:distance, s:speed, c:color} */
 
    [
     {t:65, r:(cx-40),  d:10, s:50, c:C[4]},
       {t:65, r:(cx-50),  d:12, s:50, c:C[4]},
     
    ],
    
  ];
```

somebody Help me for solve my problem
Thanks All

Help for solve my problem